# Kali linux update and package installation error

Tags: vmware, kali-linux, apt-get

i installed `anonsurf` on Kali Linux in `VMware` and now i can't use `apt-get install`  or `apt-get update`
and i can't uninstall it or stop it i don't know why

> You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> beef : Depends: libcattle-1.0-0 (>= 1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
> kali-anonsurf : Depends: i2p but it is not going to be installed
> Recommends: gtkdialog but it is not installable
> Recommends: gufw but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

this is the error of tring to install a package

> Err:1 https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
> Temporary failure resolving 'http.kali.org'
> Err:2 http://deb.i2p2.no unstable InRelease
> Temporary failure resolving 'deb.i2p2.no'
> Reading package lists... Done
> W: Failed to fetch https://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'http.kali.org'
> W: Failed to fetch http://deb.i2p2.no/dists/unstable/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.i2p2.no'
> W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

and this is the error of `apt-get update`
i tried `apt-get remove anonsurf` but it says unable to locate package `anonsurf`
also, `anonsurf` works when i use `anonsurf -h` or any `anonsurf` command
i deleted the `anonsurf` directory from root and nothing happened and i tried `anonsurf stop` and `anonsurf stopi2p` didn't work so how to fix this

```
                                                                                                      Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: never mind i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the Kali repository. It can be fixed by adding following lines to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p.list

deb https://deb.i2p2.de/ buster main
deb-src https://deb.i2p2.de/ buster main

Then, run apt update